# How can i select distinct or group column and count in a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here's the table:

[image]

I want to select every employee_id and credit_date(distinct/group) with total number of credit_date occurrence. Can anyone help me? or give me hint for this?

Example output:

```
|  employee_id  |  credit_date  |  count  |
|    00810      |  2017-05-17   |    1    |
|    00810      |  2017-05-19   |    4    |
|    00810      |  2017-05-20   |    4    |
```

and so on. . .

Thanks advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

very simple `GROUP BY`. Try like this:

```
SELECT employee_id, credit_date, COUNT(credit_date) AS count
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY employee_id, credit_date
HAVING COUNT(credit_date) > 5
```

Comment: I have a follow up question sir, how can i make it select only those count greater than or equal to 5?

Comment: If you work hard, It happens very much :) your welcome.

Comment: with `HAVING` clause : `HAVING COUNT(credit_date) > 5`

Comment: SELECT employee_id, credit_date, COUNT(credit_date) AS count
FROM tableName
WHERE count >= 5
GROUP BY employee_id, credit_date
ORDER by employee_id.

it says column "count" does not exist

Comment: not by `WHERE`. use `HAVING`. I updated my answer. check it please.

Comment: thanks so much for the time. it worked. first time using "HAVING" . . :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153324/discussion-between-winnie-damayo-and-ali-adlavaran).

Answer (score 1):

```
Select empid,credit_date,count(credit_date) from table group by empid,credit_date;
```

It groups empid and inside the empid group it groups the records using credit_date. Now you can get what you actually want.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information sir. although your answer is pretty similar with @Ali Adlavaran. I upvote for the additional explanation.